# How to resolve this issue Error: Type 'DecoderCallback' not found

Tags: flutter, dart

Error (Xcode): ../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/photo_manager-2.8.1/lib/src/internal/image_provider.dart:71:5: Error: Type 'DecoderCallback' not found.

### Issue Description

When running my Flutter project on an iPhone 11, I encounter the following error related to `DecoderCallback`:

And I have added advance_image_picker: ^0.1.7+1 plugin in which it was showing error of photo_manager.

flutter version is 3.16.0

Answer (score 0):

Please import 2 packages, photo_manager of version over 3.0(3.0.0-dev.1 to 3.0.0-dev.5),
and photo_manager_image_provider.

Migration between photo_manager version 2.0 and 3.0 was written in the link below:
https://github.com/fluttercandies/flutter_photo_manager/blob/main/MIGRATION_GUIDE.md#assetentityimage-and-assetentityimageprovider

Comment: Thanks for reply @Daichi Fujiwara. I did added the first plugin of photo_manager but for flutter 3.16.0 its deprecated now and about this issue I have to change my sdk version and the thing is I don't wanted to rechange my flutter version.

Answer (score 0):

Add photo_manager to your pubspec and install, that removed the error for me with the upgraded flutter version.

Comment: Thanks for reply @Katie Lewise, actually my issue has been resolved the problem was that the function of DecoderCallBack in Advance Image Picker has been deprecated so in its place another function had to be used which is decodeImageBytes(Unit8Lists)